# What does "strain of opinion" mean?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

I'd like to know the meaning of strain in the phrase "strain of opinion". Is there any synonym for it? Look at the following sentences including it.

> Though it may be difficult to imagine from a later perspective, **a strain of critical opinion** in the 1920's predicted that sound film would be a technical novelty that would soon fade from sight, just as had many previous attempts, dating well back before the First World War, to link images with recorded sound. [Official TOEFL IBT Test, Vol.2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although as Jeffrey Carney has stated the word *strain* can be used here I wonder whether it was a slip for *strand*. For what it is worth [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=strain+of+opinion%2Cstrand+of+opinion&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstrain%20of%20opinion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstrand%20of%20opinion%3B%2Cc0) shows *strand of opinion* as becoming much more common from about the last half of the last century although *strain of opinion* was more common before that.

Comment: That's good. As I pondered the sentence, the word "thread" kept coming to mind. Plus, in the age of Covid, "strain" sounds a little sinister.

Comment: This is a great answer to me. In fact, before posting my question, I looked up Cambridge Dictionary and found the meaning offered by Jeffrey, but what prompted me to ask this question was that when I looked up other dictionaries like Oxford, Longman, Collins, I could not find such meaning. So, as you mention this meaning of "strain" is somehow old-fashion.

Answer (score 2):

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/strain#:%7E:text=a%20particular%20type%20or%20quality) provides this meaning:

> a particular type or quality:
> *A strain of puritanism runs through all her work.*

So your passage means something like this:

> A number of critics with similar opinions believed that . . .